# Doxygen's double hash-tags / number-signs (##) are not PEP8 conform (E266)

Tags: python, doxygen, pep8

To document class members in Python for Doxygen you have to annotate them with two number-signs / hash-tags (`##`).

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    ## This is a public member
    self.bar = 7
```

But PEP8 code checkers (e.g. `pycodestyle`) take this as an error ([E266](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E266.html)).

Of course I can set the specific error to ignore. But his is a workaround not a solution.

The question is if there is any other solution for Doxygen to annotate class members without violating PEP8?

Comment: You could try the standard python docstrings.

Comment: What is a "standard python docstring" in that case? It need to be recognized by doxygen, too.

Comment: Something with `"""` or `"""!`

Comment: """! does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@albert and @Mathy answered this in the comments.

Using `"""!` instead of `##` would help.

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    """! This is a public member"""
    self.bar = 7
```